# Retrieving data from a dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

I am sorry if this question has been asked before, i have tried using google but all the answers couldn't help me.

I am a total begginer in using datasets and connecting to database using c#. I have a dataset `usersDataset` gotten from an access 2007 Database that has two table `Administrators` and `Users`. Both tables have two columns `UserName` and `Password`. The `Administrators Table` has a row of data.

Now the problem is that i want to retrive the row in the dataset. I have tried many things but they all throw an Exception.

I have tried

```
    DataRow rows = usersDataset1.Administrators.Rows[0];
    MessageBox.Show(rows.ToString());
```

Also tried

```
   usersDataset data = new usersDataset();
   MessageBox.Show(data.Administrators.Rows[0].ToString());
```

Also tried

```
   MessageBox.Show(usersDataset1.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString());
```

All of the following code snippets throw an `IndexOutofRangeException` with the message `There is no Row at Index 0`.

Then i tried

```
   MessageBox.Show(usersDataset1.Administrators.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

It shows '0'.

Pls what did i do wrong and how can i correct it?

**EDIT :** When i drag the Administrator from the DataSources Windom to the form and i run the Application. The row is displayed.

Comment: Administrators table doesn't have any row. You need to check that.

Comment: Set a break point and make sure you have in fact any rows in the Administrators table.

Comment: Do you have a piece of code that connects to the database and populates the dataset before you try getting data out of it? Can we see it?

Comment: @nhrobin I am sure there is a row in it. I have previewed it using it the DataSources window

Comment: @DanielGabriel No. i already added the row to the database before connecting to it using the Server Explorer

Comment: That's not my question though. You have to have code that takes the information from your database table and puts it into your dataset, before you can read it from the dataset. Do you have such code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current problem (as evidenced by your last example) is that you have no data in the Administrators table.  Perhaps you aren't properly loading your data into your data structure?

On a side note, it's generally better to iterate through the rows in a table unless you will always know exactly how many rows it will contain.  For example:

```
foreach (DataRow row in usersDataset1.Administrators.Rows)
{
  //Do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: Tried it but no action is performed

Comment: When i drag the administrator table from the data sources window to the form and i run the app. The row is displayed.

Comment: Double check the SQL you are using to populate the dataset. Looks like the syntax is correct since you aren't seeing errors but perhaps the SQL simple doesn't return any rows.

Comment: @rheitzman hit the nail on the head - if that query doesn't put any rows in the dataset, then it's the query that's wrong.